# PDF image text missing

Tags: macos, browser, pdf, osx-yosemite, adobe-reader

I can view the following PDF without problems in a web browser (tried more than once).

https://s3.amazonaws.com/video.udacity-data.com/topher/2017/December/5a24786e_dsfnd-handbook/dsfnd-handbook.pdf

However, after I save the PDF and open in Adobe Acrobat Reader, some text/images are missing.

Any idea why this is happening? Any solution to this?

Machine: MBPRetina OSX 10.10

Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version: 15.17

Example screenshots of page 3:

[page 3 in Adobe Reader program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z71CS.png)

[page 3 in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqf2c.png)

Comment: What does it look like in Preview? Works fine for me, but I'm on 10.13.4

Comment: For example, page 3 is missing the text. I.e. it just shows a white box

Comment: @Testsujin I've tried viewing the file on another machine (Win7) and also on a newer version (18) Adobe Reader. However, the same problem persists

Comment: still haven't answered the question...

Comment: @Testsujin Sorry I thought I answered your question in the earlier comment. Let me try again:
In the Preview (I assume you mean in the browser view?), it contains text/images e.g. page 3 shows the following text: (Meet the Team
Your Resources
The Content
What to Expect
4
6
8
11). However, in the Acrobat Reader no text is shown...Please see the new images in the question.

Comment: I mean the Apple app, Preview - the default pdf reader on Mac.

Comment: Apologies...It shows the correct format i.e. with texts and images (no problems)

Comment: OK, & I can confirm it's broken on Windows IE 11 - so I think it's a formatting error from whoever made it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for confirming! Appreciate your time and help